# Windows Messages Privileges

Tags: windows, delphi, privileges, windows-messages

what are the windows messages privileges?

In the Application 1, I posted a message to Application 2:

```
PostMessage(handle, WM_LOCAL, 0, Integer(Lst));
```

In the Application 2, The Message Implementation:

```
var l: TStringList;
begin    
  ShowMessage('got 1');
  l := TStringList(Message.LParam);
  ShowMessage('got 2');
  Memo1.Clear;
  ShowMessage('got 3');

  if Memo1 = nil then
    ShowMessage('nil');

  //HERE : Access violation.
  //Memo1.Text := l.Text;
  //ShowMessage('got 4');

  Memo1.Lines.Add('good!');
  ShowMessage('got 5');

  l.Free;      
  ShowMessage('got 6');

  //Access violation Too..
  Memo1.Repaint;
  ShowMessage('got 7');
```

Why this happens?

Neither i can repaint the Memo, nor Access the Text property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not share objects between applications. Even the pointer would point to the adressspace of the destination.
Maybe [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will fit your requirements in copying data.

Comment: there is no way I can serialize the object?

Answer (score 4):

It's not messages that have privileges, rather it is processes. The functionality is known as [User Interface Privilege Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation) (UIPI). This functionality stops lower integrity level processes sending messages to higher integrity level processes.

But that's not your problem. Your problem is that each process has a separate address space. And so a pointer from one process means nothing in a different process. Which is why you encounter an access violation. The pointer that you receive points to memory in a different process and so is meaningless.

You need to use an inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism. For example, sending a `WM_COPYDATA` message, or named pipes, or sockets and so on.

Comment: there is no way I can serialize the object?

Comment: Please don't change the subject. You asked this question and we answered this question. If you change the question, our efforts are wasted.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas  You can always ask another question ;)